# Using Schema.org for extension plugin info

Tags: schema.org

I've browsed the web for quite some time now, and have a good grasp on how Schema.org works. Now, it comes to mind that one could use Schema.org to let search engines know that this or that website is using particular software on the website, given that some functionality is provided to it. On the other hand, I can't find any references of major players doing so (WordPress, WooCommerce, Magento), so I was wondering:

1. How would I mark my piece of software, using Schema.org, on customer's website?
2. What exactly can I add as info to it (name, author, URLs, desc)?
3. Which types/properties should be used?

To add to point question 3, [`SoftwareApplication`](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) seems pretty much like something that would cover it. In Schema.org’s own examples, like following:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Restaurant",
  "name": "Tartine Bakery",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "target": [
      "http://www.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
      {
        "@type": "EntryPoint",
        "urlTemplate": "http://api.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
        "contentType": "application/json+ld"
      },
      "android-app://com.urbanspoon/http/www.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
      {
        "@type": "EntryPoint",
        "urlTemplate": "urbanspoon://r/6/92204",
        "actionApplication": {
          "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
          "@id": "284708449",
          "name": "Urbanspoon iPhone & iPad App",
          "operatingSystem": "iOS"
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "EntryPoint",
        "urlTemplate": "urbanspoon://r/6/92204",
        "actionApplication": {
          "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
          "@id": "5b23b738-bb64-4829-9296-5bcb59bb0d2d",
          "name": "Windows Phone App",
          "operatingSystem": "Windows Phone 8"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Schema.org is used to provide info about an restaurant (why not software?). So, if anyone has an idea of how can this be done, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org doesn’t offer a property to specify the [`SoftwareApplication`](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) that was used for generating a [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite)/[`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage).

The [`isBasedOn`](http://schema.org/isBasedOn) property might be used, given its broad definition ("A resource that was used in the creation of this resource."), but I guess it was not intended for this purpose.

Instead of specifying the software that is used for generating the pages (which is typically not interesting for consumers, especially since it doesn’t necessarily follow that certain features are available), it might make more sense to [specify the potential actions](http://schema.org/potentialAction) offered by the site/pages:

- [`RegisterAction`](http://schema.org/RegisterAction)
- [`CommentAction`](http://schema.org/CommentAction)
- [`SearchAction`](http://schema.org/SearchAction)
- [`BuyAction`](http://schema.org/BuyAction)
- etc.

And from such an `Action`, you could use (where applicable) the [`target`](http://schema.org/target) property to specify an [`EntryPoint`](http://schema.org/EntryPoint) which can specify with [`actionApplication`](http://schema.org/actionApplication) which software is used to "complete the request".

(By the way, you can specify the software that was used to generate the HTML document as meta tag, no need for structured data: [`generator`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#generator))

Comment: Helps enough. Though, it could be a tad more helpful to others if there were some examples